# Sailor, but of rivers

Tags: single-word-requests, class-based-usage

I'm looking for a word similar to 'sailor' but not of the oceans (i.e rivers).  Sailors are assumed to be 'people of the high seas' etc, which isn't what I'm after - I need smaller bodies of water.  Someone who rides not a *ship* but a boat/kayak/canoe, but a general term so not 'kayaker', 'canoer' etc.

> He was the ___ of the River Thames.

Comment: In the US, men of the river were normally *boatmen*, not sailors.

Comment: Pretty sure that "boatman" is/was used in England as well.  At least I'm remembering it in some British/Scottish folk songs.  But a lot likely has to do with the waterway -- a "boatman" is skilled in navigating narrow rivers and canals, while a "sailor" is skilled in the open seas, wide harbors, etc.

Comment: @Lordology "Boatman" is certainly used in Britain. The only people known as "sailors" on inland waterways are those that actually operate under sail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sailor is merely someone who works on a ship or boat of any size, either for employment or pleasure. There is no restriction in meaning to ocean-going vessels, and people who sail on the Thames are often called "Thames sailors".

> It is said that many an experienced Thames sailor delays a passage
>   with a [gale force] 5 or 6 in the [weather] forecast!
>
> Benson, I should explain, was the experienced Thames sailor and Mr
>   Fixit who looked after Lewis Jones' boat.
>
> Now I'm not an inexperienced Thames sailor...I've done the disco boat,
>   the gentle steamer, the bus boat, the high speed jet boats
>
> The role of leading innovator in the class was taken on by another
>   Thames sailor, Mike Jackson.

Comment: I had an inkling.  I was just checking to see if there was a word, but well done.

Comment: Search Google for "Thames sailor", using quotes around the phrase.

Answer (score 4):

[Watermen, wherrymen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterman_(occupation)) and [Lightermen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lighterman)

In 1510, Henry VIII granted a licence (a form of licensed public transport) to watermen, giving exclusive rights to carry passengers on the river...An Act of Parliament in 1555 formalized the trade and  established the Company of Watermen and Lightermen.

For more than 450 years, watermen and lightermen have plied their trade on the capital's river. It takes as long to qualify to captain a boat on the stretch of water between Teddington and Gravesend as it does to pick up A-levels and a university degree. But yesterday [1st Jan 2007] a new **boatmaster**'s licence came into force which, the **boatmen** claim, threatens safety and their livelihoods. https://www.theguardian.com/uk/2007/jan/02/britishidentity.patrickbarkham

Famous watermen
John Taylor (1580–1653), [the Water Poet.](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Taylor,_John_(1580-1653)_(DNB00))

However I consider for the past decade and going forwards we would have to use

> He was the **boatman** bard of the River Thames.

He described himself as "John Taylor, the Water-Poet, alias the King's Majesties Water-Poet and 
Queen's **Waterman**,.." a custom-house officer, an adventurer by 
sea and land, a licensed victualler, writer and publisher of short pieces in prose 
and verse for upwards of forty years, a peripatetic bookseller, a tuft-hunter, a 
very great schemer, and a firm Royalist with a lame leg [!"](https://archive.org/stream/worksofjohntaylo00tayl/worksofjohntaylo00tayl_djvu.txt)

Another of his eccentric freaks was to start one Saturday evening along with a vintner on a voyage from London to Queenborough in Kent, in a brown-paper boat with two stockfish tied to two canes for oars; before he and his companion had covered three miles the paper bottom fell to pieces; though they ultimately reached their destination on Monday morning more dead than alive. Shortly after this Taylor fulfilled a wagering journey to Bohemia (1620), and at Prague enjoyed the queen's bounty;

Watermen and lightermen received double rations during the war because of their crucial role. Traditionally, they are also the only members of the public permitted to touch royalty - to help them into boats. The most elite of such boatmen include swan uppers [(see Vintners and Dyers)](https://vintnershall.co.uk/swans/)

Comment: Waterman, wherryman, and lighterman are names of specific occupations, job titles, which involve  boats on the Thames. They are not generic like 'sailor' is.

Answer (score 1):

There is the term *[**riverman**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/riverman)*:

> 1: one who lives and works on or along a river
> 2: a river driver  *[a person who drives logs on a river]*
> 3: a deckhand on a riverboat
> <sub>*definition from [merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/riverman)*</sub>
>
> Originally: a man who lives on a river; (in later use) a man who earns his living on a river.
> <sub>*definition from [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/riverman)*</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Pilot ?

They're always super experienced - at least about their own stretch of fresh water.

Here's one definition
A maritime pilot, also known as a marine pilot, harbor pilot or bar pilot and sometimes simply called a pilot, is a sailor who maneuvers ships through dangerous or congested waters, such as harbors or river mouths. They are normally a former ship captain and a highly experienced shiphandler possessing detailed knowledge of the particular waterway, e.g. actual depth, direction and strength of the wind, current and tide at any time of the day. The pilot is a navigational expert for the port of call.

- you'll see the emphasis on 'highly experienced'

or, as others have said 'Waterman' implies fresh water capability and knowledge with practical attributes.
again, here's a definition
Waterman (occupation), a river worker who transferred passengers across and along the city centre rivers in Britain

But this is more relevant 
The Company of Watermen and Lightermen of the River Thames was founded in 1514, when the earliest Act of Parliament for regulating watermen, wherrymen and bargemen received  Royal Assent from King Henry VIII.

Under a further Act of 1555  the Company introduced apprenticeships for those wishing to learn the skills of the Watermen. In 1700 the Lightermen (carriers of goods/cargo) joined  the Watermen’s Company.

In 1780 The Company moved into its own purpose built Hall – Watermen’s Hall,  located at St Mary at Hill, which is where we can be  found today.

The Company is a working guild and is very actively involved with the life of the River and those who work on it.

Comment: Hi Andrea, welcome to EL&U. This isn't a bad start, but it's too short: the system has flagged it as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. Can I suggest you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a published definition of *pilot* (linked to the source) and perhaps how broadly the term can be used? For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - I've added more details.